# How do I determine the correct .dll when Excel VBA causes Error 429?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel Help says a component cannot be found or may be corrupted in the registry (Error 429).  How do I find what the component is, and how do I fix it for Excel?

I am running a sub from a button on the spreadsheet.  I commented out all of the code, a few lines at a time, so I assumed the problem was the button. Error 429 showed up with and without the code commented out. Help said that dao360.dll had to be added to:
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll
which I did.  (I had to add the sub-folder, DAO, which was missing.)  I copied dao360.dll (3.60.9765.0) from the library, "Microsoft 3.6 Object Library", and added it to the \DAO library. The code still produced error 429.
I am running Windows 11 64 bit and Excel 365 64 bit Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20170. Both are up to date.

Comment: Adding and moving DLLs around the Program Files folder willy-nilly is never the solution. Most of them have dependencies on other files, that you'll never be able to locate and/or get in the proper locations. I'd suggest that you [edit] your post to add the **complete, exact error message** that you're getting, and stop just fumbling around with things until you get some help, so that you don't make things worse or break something else.

Comment: Object libraries like dao360.dll need to be registered, e.g. using regsvr32.exe. However you are probably better off re-installing or repairing Excel instead of monkeying with the files yourself.